# Serving react static files in golang gin-gonic using go:embed giving 404 error on reloading on frontend URL

Tags: reactjs, go, embed, go-gin

I have built a go application using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) and go1.17.

I am using `go:embed` to to serve static content for a SPA app built using react.
(trying the approach as suggested in https://github.com/gin-contrib/static/issues/19).
My frontend files are in a build folder

```
build/index.html
build/asset-manifest.json
build/static/css/**
build/static/js/**
build/manifest.json
```

```
//go:embed build/*
var reactStatic embed.FS

type embedFileSystem struct {
    http.FileSystem
    indexes bool
}

func (e embedFileSystem) Exists(prefix string, path string) bool {
    f, err := e.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    // check if indexing is allowed
    s, _ := f.Stat()
    if s.IsDir() && !e.indexes {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func EmbedFolder(fsEmbed embed.FS, targetPath string, index bool) static.ServeFileSystem {
    subFS, err := fs.Sub(fsEmbed, targetPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return embedFileSystem{
        FileSystem: http.FS(subFS),
        indexes:    index,
    }
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    fs := EmbedFolder(reactStatic, "build", true)

    //Serve frontend static files
    router.Use(static.Serve("/", fs))
    /* THESE ARE MY STATIC URLs FROM THE REACT APP in FRONTEND  */
    router.Use(static.Serve("/login", fs))
    router.Use(static.Serve("/calendar", fs))

    router.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(404, gin.H{
            "code": "PAGE_NOT_FOUND", "message": "Page not found",
        })
    })

    setupBaseRoutes(router, database)

    httpServerExitDone := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    httpServerExitDone.Add(1)

    srv, ln := server.StartServer(router, httpServerExitDone)

    log.Printf("Starting Server at %s", ln.Addr().String())

    quit := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt)
    <-quit
    log.Println("Shutdown Server ...")

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Server Shutdown:", err)
    }
    log.Println("Server exiting")
}
```

When the application loads and the page `http://localhost:8000/` is opened it opens properly and I can navigate to `http://localhost:8000/calendar` using react-router-dom.
But when I reload the page `http://localhost:8000/calendar`, I get 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

I made the following comment on that [github issue](https://github.com/gin-contrib/static/issues/19#issuecomment-1104616942):

I was able to get this working for my SPA, serving from a *wwwroot* embedded directory with a minor hack in the `NoRoute` handler to always return `index.html`. I was originally simply trying to do:

```golang
//go:embed wwwroot
var app embed.FS
```

```golang
wwwroot := embedFolder(app, "wwwroot")

router.Use(static.Serve("/", wwwroot))
router.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.FileFromFS("index.html", wwwroot)
})
```

but this doesn't play well with how the [http.serveFile function](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.1:src/net/http/fs.go;l=592;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.18.1) always performs a local redirect to `"/"` when the path ends with `/index.html`. So instead of `"index.html"`, I tried `""`, `"/"`, `"wwwroot"`, and `"wwwroot/"`, but all of those failed because that wasn't actually a file in the embedded file system.

My solution was to re-write the request URL to the default empty path and re-use the `static.Serve` middleware since it can handle the `"/"` path by calling it manually:

```golang
wwwroot := embedFolder(app, "wwwroot")
staticServer := static.Serve("/", wwwroot)

router.Use(staticServer)
router.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
    if c.Request.Method == http.MethodGet &&
        !strings.ContainsRune(c.Request.URL.Path, '.') &&
        !strings.HasPrefix(c.Request.URL.Path, "/api/") {
        c.Request.URL.Path = "/"
        staticServer(c)
    }
})
```

Note that I'm only doing this for `GET` requests that don't contain a `'.'` or start with my API prefix so I should still get a `404` error for API routes and files that don't exist, like if I used a bad image path.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a workaround by renaming `build/index.html` to `build/index.htm`

Due to some reason, `index.html` is hard-coded in some golang library used by gin, which results in 404 on page reload.

I read about it in a Github issue but can't seem to find the link to that issue now.

Comment: Maybe you are refering to this function? https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/net/http/fs.go;l=604

I can confirm that renaming the file works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this bro, just improve from this repository [mandrigin/gin-spa](https://github.com/mandrigin/gin-spa)

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/static"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var (
    //go:embed build
    reactDir embed.FS
)

func EmbedReact(urlPrefix, buildDirectory string, em embed.FS) gin.HandlerFunc {
    dir := static.LocalFile(buildDirectory, true)
    embedDir, _ := fs.Sub(em, buildDirectory)
    fileserver := http.FileServer(http.FS(embedDir))

    if urlPrefix != "" {
        fileserver = http.StripPrefix(urlPrefix, fileserver)
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if !dir.Exists(urlPrefix, c.Request.URL.Path) {
            c.Request.URL.Path = "/"
        }
        fileserver.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
        c.Abort()
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(EmbedReact("/", "build", reactDir))
    r.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

Go, Gin & React

```
engine := gin.Default()
engine.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./client/build", true)))
engine.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.File("./client/build/index.html")
})
err := engine.Run(":8080")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly simpler way that's working for me:

```golang
//go:embed build
var reactStatic embed.FS

static, err := fs.Sub(reactStatic, "build")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

r := gin.Default()
r.StaticFS("/", http.FS(reactStatic))
```